# Get the visitors that have only revisited one day or more

Tags: sql

I have this SQL query to get all the visitors that have been online more than once since their first visit:

```
SELECT COUNT(date_lastactive)
FROM visitors
WHERE date_lastactive != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Because of its simpleness, every revisited visitors are listed. I don't want that! I want to only get visitors that have been revisited the website one day and more (2 days, 3 days, 5 month, 8 months, 2 years, and so on but **not** under 1 day such as 4 hours or something like that).

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How you track when their first visit was?

Comment: On a side note, if they've never visited, the field should be `NULL`.

Comment: @G. Stoynev: Each time a visitor visits my website, I record their visit by using another SQL query. That query updates `date_firstvisit` to the given date and time, and even log their IP address so I can identify the visitor. When this visitor reloads the page, `date_lastactive` gets the current date and time for given IP address. It's very simple actually :)

Comment: In that case FreshPrinceOfSO's answer is not giving you what you're asking for, because FreshPrinceOfSO is not factoring that date_firstvisit. His answer is returning everybody who up to 24 hours back from NOW(), even if they visited only once.

Comment: @G. Stoynev: That is very true! Many thanks for that observation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL (MS SQL Server syntax):

```
SELECT COUNT(some_visitor_id)
FROM visitors
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, date_lastactive, date_firstvisit) > 1
```

not 100% certain about the SQL dialect that FreshPrinceOfSO is using, but I guess it'll be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(some_visitor_id)
FROM visitors
WHERE date_lastactive >= DATE_ADD(date_firstvisit, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to perform a calculation to subtract 1 day from [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

```
WHERE date_lastactive > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: That's very true :) Many thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. This answer will give you people who visited in the last day